# Deleting Old Data Service from DSS and adding new Data Service with Same Name

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

While adding a new data service in WSO2 DSS getting following error

DS Fault Message: Data Service name is already exists. Please choose different name for 'RDStockOrderHeader_DataService' data service.
DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR

Previously we had a Data Service with name RDStockOrderHeader_DataService but we deleted from UI

Comment: Check whether the service is gone from: [DSS HOME]\repository\deployment\server\dataservices. If not, you can delete it from there, and then try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to follow below steps:

1. Please check the dbs file is deleted from below location.
   /repository/deployment/server/dataservices
2. If dss file deleted then please refresh the browser or sign-out and sing-in back and you won't be able to see the existing deployed dss service in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please give a try with below option?

1. Make sure Data Service file removed from file system

If you have done deployment using "DBS" file then go go below location and make sure that data service file doesn't exists here

```
<WSO2-DSS>/repository/deployment/server/dataservices
```

If you have done deployment using "CAR" file then go go below location and make sure that data service car file doesn't exists here

```
<WSO2-DSS>/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps/
```

2. Restart DSS node